# How to resolve React: "Failed to compile; ./src/App.js" error while creating webapp

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I got following error on localhost when I start my react app. It highlights 36 row "export default App;":

```
./src/App.js SyntaxError:
C:\Users\Windows\MarketerSearch\marketersearch\src\App.js: Unexpected
token (36:7)

34 |   );

35 | }

36 | export default App;
```

Visual Studio shows these errors:

[image: Visual Studio shows this error]

Please find app.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { client } from './client';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articles: []    
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    client.getEntries()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(console.error)
  }

  render()  {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className='container'>
          <header>
            <div className='wrapper'>
            <span>React and contentful</span>
            </div>
          </header>
          <main>
            <div className='wrapper'>
            
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I couldn't understand the reason behind this error. What I have missed or what's wrong in the code that Fail to compile the app.

Can you please help me fix this issue?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You're missing a `}` to close your class after the `render()` method.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. To learn, I had closed render() method. with } above export default App; why it wouldn't worked?

Comment: Because you only had a single `}` there, yet you had to close the `{` from both `render() {` and `class App ... {`.

Comment: Thank you, so much Kelvin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a syntax error. Missing closing bracket of class (App) before export default

[image: Missing closing bracket]